# Can we save multiple faces for face recognition using OpenCV in android

Tags: android

Hi I've been trying to develop an app that needs to store multiple faces but it's not working as expected it's only saving one face at a time once you record a new face it will just override the existing face.  Is it possible?

Comment: You know it's possible. That's not the question you're really asking.  You've copied and pasted some code from some tutorial verbatim, that you don't really understand, and you'd like someone to write the rest of the code for you (or find you another tutorial with a much more complete project to begin with). Am I about right?

Comment: Hi Stephan,

Yeah somehow you're right I can't understand much of the code I though I can.  :(